# Parabolic Arrhenius plot

Tags: kinetics, enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

I am currently doing a kinetic study on an enzyme catalysed reaction and plotting the Arrhenius graph ($\ln k$ vs $1/T$) and I got a parabola. My idea is to take the derivative at each point, meaning there would be different activation energies depending on the temperature, guessing it is due to enzymes dependency to heat. Does it make sense or would it be data forcing?

The parabola has the following shape:
[image]
so I am 99% sure it is a parabola. The only other possibility I see is to divide it in two straight lines but I don't know how to interpret it.

And the data is the following:

| 1/T | ln(k) |
| --- | --- |
| 0.029412 | 3.35 |
| 0.028571 | 3.42 |
| 0.027778 | 4.18 |
| 0.027027 | 4.95 |
| 0.026316 | 5.67 |
| 0.025641 | 3.97 |
| 0.025 | 3.12 |
| 0.024390 | 1.41 |
| 0.023809 | 0.88 |

Temperature range is from 34 up to 42ºC (scale: 1ºC); 5 tries per temperature

The experiment was the following:

I prepared a 1% concentration solution of amylase and a 1% concentration solution of starch. I added lugol to starch in order to get a purple colored complex. I heated both amylase and starch to the desired temperature and then I let them react in a spectrophotometer, getting an absorbance vs time graph of this kind:
[image]

Using Beer-Lambert law I obtained the concentration vs time graph, and then I calculated the initial rate taking the derivative at $t=0$ of the best fit curve. Finally I computed $k$ and I plotted the Arrhenius graph

Comment: Much depends not just on the enzyme but on the T range, number of points. Is it a smooth curve? You can just fit a polynomial in that case.

Comment: I am going to modify the question in order to add this data, thank you for your answers !

Comment: I don't suppose you performed any of the measurements multiple times? It certainly looks like the rate peaks, but I wouldn't hazard a guess of the functional form from this data. It's too scattered for that, especially w/o uncertainty estimates on the data points (nice data all the same). Not sure it makes sense to think in terms of Arrhenius constants with data that peaks like this and with such a narrow T range.

Comment: What you are observing is a typical manifestation of an "Arrhenius break" (at the transition temperature $38\;^\circ \rm C$) because of the conformational changes of enzyme due to denaturation. To calculate $E_a$, you would usually disregard the values above the transition temperature and use only values below it, which – as can be clearly seen from your plot – lie on a nice line as the Arrhenius equation predicts. Take a look at [this exemplary article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268187086_Kinetics_and_thermodynamic_studies_of_alpha_amylase_from_Bacillus_licheniformis_mutant).

Comment: You may yet be able to find a more complex model: https://edepot.wur.nl/546299

Comment: I did not know about Arrhenius break but it seems you are completely right. Thank you very much to all for your help, have a nice day !